# Convert multisheet excel .xls to .xlsx

Tags: unix, xls

I need to convert .xls to .xlsx in order to do some processing. I need this to be done in unix server. Tried with libreoffice , simple extension change etc. Nothing seems to be working out. Will there be any solutions to do this?

Comment: I think it would help is you described what you're trying to accomplish to make sure we don't have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. What sort of solution are you looking for? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I have the multi sheet excel.xls in my unix environment , I need that whole .xls to be converted to .xlsx , since that is the input for the next system. So I am looking for some commands or some jar files that can be executed in unix to convert my .xls to .xlsx

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved. We have created a  java code and a shell script to convert xls/xlsx to csv.